# He/Him buttering sunscreen on my back

Tags: word-choice, personal-pronouns, case, subject-vs-object-pronouns

> We were vacationing at the beach, **I/me** sprawled on my towel, **he/him** buttering sunscreen on my back.

What should be the correct choice and why?

My intuition tells me that **me** ... **him** is the correct choice but I'm not very sure.

(Sorry, I don't know the name of these type of construction, so I couldn't write a better title.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be idiomatic you would not use the nominative case there but **me** and **him**.

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say, because either way this is not a grammatically correct sentence. That doesn't mean that a fluent speaker wouldn't say it, especially in informal speech.

A grammatically correct sentence would be, "We were vacationing at the beach: I was sprawled on my towel; he was buttering sunscreen on my back." (Or you could break it into three sentences, or many other possible variations.)

All that said, I think most English speakers would say me/him.

Comment: Why do you say it's ungrammatical? It means the same thing as *We— me sprawled on my towel, him buttering sunscreen on my back— were vacationing at the beach.* I probably wouldn't use this construction in business writing, but that's because of its informality, not its grammaticality.

Comment: The sentence, in either version, is perfectly grammatical. If you consider it ungrammatical, what grammar errors do you see in it? Are you saying it is a run-on (which I think clearly it is not)? Also, worth noting the OP is an active user on Writer.SE and a publisher author (That's enough, Google). This style of writing is extremely common in contemporary fiction writing. I don't think I'd go through a single book picked out from the fiction section of a book store without encountering a sentence similar in structure to this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think him and me would be a correct usage there.

A correct sentence would be:

> We were vacationing at the beach, I sprawled on my towel while he buttered sunscreen on my back.

Comment: Did you mean to say "_in_ my towel"? It seems like _on_ is the better preposition there.

Comment: I wrote "in" because i thought you meant to say you were wearing the towel. my bad. Lying on  the towel or sprawling on the towel will be correct